# Bootstrap FormGroup/ Input is not fully visible (Half hidden by some layers) only in IOS

Tags: css, ios, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I am working on a form group that has an input with bootstrap, it works fine in all the desktop platforms, as well as in Android, but for some weird reasons, it's not fully showing or only showing a half-hidden input field, check the images below.

Android (Works just fine)

[image]

***This how it is showing in IOS (***Issue***)***

[image]

This is the written code responsible for that output.

```
<div className="form-group search-div">
          <form className='form' ref={form} onSubmit={handleSearch}>
            <button className="search-button" >
              <div className="search-icon">
                <span >{SEARCH_ICON}</span>
              </div>
            </button>
            <input
              type="search"
              className="search-input"
              name="searcText"
              value={searchText}
              onChange={onChangeUsername}
              placeholder="Search"
              aria-label="Search"
              aria-describedby="search-addon" />
          </form>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
.search-input {
  /* position: inherit; */
  width: calc(100% - 50px);
  height: 18px;
  /* left: 45px; */
  /* top: -35px; */

  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 18px;
  border: 0px;
  outline: 0px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF !important;
}
```

Simply don't know what to do here, any inputs if anyone has already worked with similar problem?

Comment: Which browser do you use on iOS? Was it Safari or Chrome?

Comment: browser is chrome

Comment: Does that occur when you use the real device or chrome desktop's inspect element?

Comment: only in real device

Comment: Can you provide those `search-` classes? Those are made by you dont they?

Comment: Yeah can you provide a jsFiddle or something we can interact with to replicate the issue?

Comment: updated css class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your `height` attribute, the input in iOS has some padding added into it, so 18px on a line-height of 18px is too small for the text height.
Try increase the height or reduce the padding in your css, based on the result you wish to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Although no fiddle is provided to test, past experience dictates to remove the `line-height:18px` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Should help if add the CSS code below to required elements (input or parent div's etc.) or related CSS classes.

```
padding-top: 0 !important;
padding-bottom: 0 !important;
```